# Context Variable renders the previous value upon refresh

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a form that accepts a file upload and fetches some interesting data from the file upon POST.

However, upon refreshing the page, the form is back to its initial state but the data from the previous file remains. How do I fix it?

Here's my code:

**forms.py**

```py
choices = (('all', 'all'),
            ('one', 'one'))

class TicketDetailForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```py
def home(request):
    detail = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TicketDetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['type'] == 'all':
                file = form.cleaned_data['file'].read()
                detail.append([str(file, 'utf-8')]) 
                # more workaround with the file
    else:
        form = TicketDetailForm()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form,
                                         'detail': detail})
```

**home.html**

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{form.as_p}}</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    {% if detail %}
        <div class="row">
            <p>The detail is as follows:</p>
            {% for d in detail %}
                {{ d }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you re-post the form when you refresh the page, since your view just renders the template even if the form is valid. The proper behaviour for a server is to **always** redirect after successfully submitting a `POST`. In other words, inside `if form.is_valid()` you should end by `return redirect('home')`.

Your views should always do the following:

- For a GET request, render the template
- For a POST request and invalid form, render the template (with the invalid form so the user can fix errors). Hitting refresh is ok here, it will just re-submit the invalid form and therefore won't cause issues.
- For a POST request and valid form, redirect, so that the last request is a GET request and the user cannot re-submit when refreshing. This also avoids the valid form to be rendered again.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a redirect to home doesn't work either. And ofcourse it does not fetch any value for the "detail" variable.

Comment: you have to explain your flow or business logic more. Normally you would have a list view showing objects saved in database. A detail view to view each object separately. And a create view where you can create a new object. When submitting the new object, you redirect to the detail view, which will show the object since it can be retrieved from db. Or to the list view, where you'll see the new object added to the list.

Comment: Yes, I get it. However, this is seems to be a peculiar case. If you notice my template, The second div is rendered only when there is a detail variable. And this detail variable has a value only upon form post. I just can't get my head around this puzzle. Duh!

Comment: Yes I understand what your template and view are doing, however I don't understand the logic of it. Isn't `detail` saved somehow to your database? If not, that means this is just a one-off? user submits something to see the results but looses the results if they leave the page?

Comment: Exactly! I don't use db here.

Comment: Then just reset your form at the end of the `form.is_valid()` section: `form = TicketDetailForm()` that way, the form rendered will be empty again.